# How to create a CreatePage which you can create a new page from page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-server, page-layout

I am new to SharePoint. I am wondering if someone could give me some direction, where I can create a new page when I click a link/record of a list, it redirect to another page under URL like:
siteurl/_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx?RootFolder=xxxxxx&ContentTypeId=xxxxxxx&Source=xxxxxxx

The CreatePage.aspx example from another site is below. I would like to create a link to this kind of page for user to create a new page using the Page Layout and name the page.

I have no idea where this CreatePage.aspx page is from and where point the link to. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The CreatePage.aspx in your post is from pages library.

You could go to site contents and find the pages library.  In the pages library, you could create a page by clicking New document in the file tab.

If you want to create a link to the create page and add the link in other list to let users create pages, you could create a hyperlink column in the list and add the link of CreatePage below into the hyperlink column.  (You should change to your site. And “858C43FF-DEF2-4B07-A7A8-9ED388784930” is the GUID of the page library in your site.)

http://sp2013:15866/_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx?List={858C43FF-DEF2-4B07-A7A8-9ED388784930}

To get the GUID of the Pages library, you could go to the pages library->library settings, find the url of the library settings as below.

http://sp2013:15866/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7B858C43FF%2DDEF2%2D4B07%2DA7A8%2D9ED388784930%7D

Then decode the url like below.

http://sp2013:15866/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List={858C43FF-DEF2-4B07-A7A8-9ED388784930}

Then copy the “?List={858C43FF-DEF2-4B07-A7A8-9ED388784930}” and append it after http://sp2013:15866/_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx

After all, the url of CreatePage like below. You could add it in another list.

http://sp2013:15866/_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx?List={858C43FF-DEF2-4B07-A7A8-9ED388784930}

You also could get the GUID of the Pages library by PowerShell command below.

$web= Get-SPWeb -identity http://sp2013:15866

$list = $web.Lists["Pages"]

$list.ID

Comment: Thank you for your reply Amy. I couldn't locate the CreatePage.aspx from either Windows Explorer or SharePoint Designer. There is no such file/page. I searched from the top level site. The URL for other similar sub site like :  (http://intranet/en-us/news/firm/_layouts/15/CreatePage.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fen-us%2Fnews%2Ffirm%2FPages&ContentTypeId=SomeContentTypeIDSome35charactersID&Source=%2Fen-us%2Fnews%2Ffirm%2FPages%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx),  I couldn't find the CreatePage in that sub site either. Any idea?

Comment: And how I can filter the page layout to only the one for this sub site? I saw other Sub Site's CreatePage has the page layout matching to the sub site. e.g. intranet/en-us/news/events/_layouts/15/createpage.aspx, it will only have (Event) Event News showing in the page layout. How I can do it for my sub site?Currently it list all the page layout. Thank you.

Comment: You could check if there is a library named "Pages" in the top level site.

Comment: Yes, but there is no page inside the Pages library called CreatePage

Comment: Then, in the Pages library, click new document in the files tab in the ribbon and select the page you want to create, then you will see the page to create page.

Comment: Thank you Amy. For the ContentTypeId, I noticed the one with filtered Page Layout has additional ID characters as mentioned in this post: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230856/how-to-find-out-what-the-contenttypeid-is-when-create-a-new-page-using-a-page-la. Is there anyway to find out which element/page those additional ID referenced to? Thank you.