# How to find out what the ContentTypeId is when create a new page using a page layout?

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-type, page-layout

I am trying to create a page which will use a pre-defined page layout from the template, but I found the page I have is different to the one created by someone else before?

This is the page layout created by others before:
[image]

The page layout I have does not filtered the page layout:
[image]

And I found the ContentTypeID in URL is different.
First one has:
ContentTypeId=0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D0019A809EE65DB42BC95CC1CAD06BFE7F4006036E9A00156450E83469752B5DDF024009A7BEF8C9F97E545A0C90A1367B6BF7E

Second one has:
ContentTypeId=0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D0019A809EE65DB42BC95CC1CAD06BFE7F400DB9B9B434FDDA14BA06795079CEA785F

I couldn't figure out the additional part in the first one's ContentTypeID is. My guessing is it maybe related to filtering.

Could someone give me some idea, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Say we wanted to inherit from “Page”, our content type used to look something this (I’ve split up the lines so it will display properly):

```
0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF3900
242457EFB8B24247815D688C526CD44D (GUID)
00
19A809EE65DB42BC95CC1CAD06BFE7F4(GUID)
00
6036E9A00156450E83469752B5DDF024(GUID)
00
9A7BEF8C9F97E545A0C90A1367B6BF7E(GUID)
```

Since you have created a page layout based on existing page layout, hence an additional GUID got appeneded.

Comment: Thank you. I found that out by trace back the parent page layout. But is there anyway to find out what the last page is? Thank you.